# Какие функции передвижения можно использовать для персонажа в юнити?

Tags: unity3d

Просмотрев несколько уроков на ютубе узнал про функции Translate и Rotate, но использовать их для физических объектов не рекомендуют - для них лучше использовать AddForce и AddTorque. Но AddForce при перемещении объекта еще и ускоряет его, чего мне не нужно. Вопрос: как двигать физический объект, не ускоряя его?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if(rigidbody.velocity.sqrMagnitude < x * x){ // Возведение в квадрат для более удобного использования
       rigidbody.addForce(0, 0, 1); // это для примера
  }
```

Кстати да, sqrMagnitude - та же magnitude, просто в ней нет того самого, пожирающего системные ресурсы квадратного корня. Как известно, возведение в квадрат намного "легче" чем квадратный корень.

Answer (score 1):

Для персонажей стоит рассмотреть систему навигации в юнити. Она сама будет двигать, ускорять, замедлять, искать путь. Ваша задача сведется к месту, куда надо передвинуть персонажа и заданию параметра скорости движения. Плюс сгенерировать карту, по которой можно двигаться. Для персонажа с управлением на уровне WASD - решить, у вас персонаж инерционный или безинерционный. Если безинерционный, что то совсем аркадное, вместо сил можно сразу выставлять скорость и угловую скорость [Пример управления скоростью напрямую в аркадной игре - официальные уроки юнити](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial/moving-player?playlist=17147).